Set a static MAC address on STM32MP157 board with OTP fuses via U-Boot
I have programmed the OTP fuses in U-Boot to set the MAC by following this guide.
https://wiki.st.com/stm32mpu/wiki/How_to_update_OTP_with_U-Boot#:~:text=The%20fuse%20command%20allows%20you,(for%20a%20temporary%20update)
This appears to have work because from boot up in U-boot I get

When I run the firmware and check the ifconfig values the MAC address of F2:AA:7A:45:5C:12 does not appear anywhere.

Does anyone know what is happening here and how I go about setting a static ethernet MAC address please?
Many thanks
Stephen

"When I run the firmware ..." - You mean like boot a Linux kernel? Did you review the kernel boot log for any messages regarding the MAC address? All you've shown is that a value from a NV storage seems to get assigned to the ethaddr environment variable. Do you know if that gets written to the/any PHY? Is there a Device Tree that is updated? BTW as a 4-year member, why are you posting screen captures of text instead of the plain text???

Did you disable CONFIG_NET_RANDOM_ETHADDR in the configuration?

Thansk Xypron, I will try that.
Is CONFIG_NET_RANDOM_ETHADDR in the U-boot config file?
